# Accessing method variables of one class in another python class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have started learning Object Oriented concepts in python. I have got this sample code below:

```
 class Student(object):
   def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age


class School(object):
  students = []
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def add_student(self, student):
    self.students.append(student)

  def show_students(self):
    print("{0} Student Roster".format(self.name))
    for s in self.students:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(s.name, s.age))




my_school = School("Quora University")
first_student = Student("Rongan Li", 20)
second_student = Student("Jason Kane", 20)
my_school.add_student(first_student)
my_school.add_student(second_student)
my_school.show_students()
```

Question:
 In the def show_students method of School class how they are accessing the construct variables of class student without instance of that class?

Comment: I think there's a deeper question here: Shouldn't `students` be an instance variable of a `School` object, as opposed to a *class* variable? The way it's set up, adding a student to *any* School will make them appear to be a student of *all* Schools. At least that's the way it looks to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first_student = Student("Rongan Li", 20)
second_student = Student("Jason Kane", 20)
```

These lines create object of student class ,first_student which has name 'Rongan Li' and age '20'.

second_student which has name 'Jason Kane' and age '20'

Now, you add these 2 objects to the list.

```
my_school.add_student(first_student)
my_school.add_student(second_student)
```

Now, when you iterate in the list

```
for s in self.students:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(s.name, s.age))
```

's' goes to first element of list, and since it is an object of class Student , 's' becomes object of student class. Now, since 's' is first element in the list and on first place you added 'Rongal Li' and 20 . So, s has 2 properties name and age. When you do s.name , it prints 'Rongal Li' and s.age prints 20

Then it goes to next element and same process is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

in the method show_students there's a for loop :

```
for s in self.students:
    print("{0}: {1}".format(s.name, s.age))
```

it loops over the list of students added by method add so inside the loop the variable "s" represent an instance of student class so s.name is a legit way of accessing an instance variable by using an instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

The students are added to `School.students` list via the `add_student` method.

```
my_school.add_student(first_student)
my_school.add_student(second_student)
```

These two lines add two references to the `School.students` list in `my_school`. So now the list has two references pointing at `first_student` and `second_student`.

You can think of the list in `my_school` at this point as

```
students = [Pointer to first_student, Pointer to second_student]
```

When you call `my_school.show_students()`, `my_school.students` list (the list above) is accessed and through the references to `first_student` and `second_student` in the list, you access the original `first_student` object and `second_student` object and can then retrieve their properties.